# Measuring the peak memory usage of multiprocessing - confusing results

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I wrote this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

import numpy.random as nr

def f(vec_size):
  """Create a big vector and wait"""
  x = nr.randint(0, pow(10, 10), vec_size)
  time.sleep(10)

n_proc = 5
vec_size = pow(10, 6)
pool = Pool(n_proc)
for _ in pool.imap_unordered(f, [vec_size] * n_proc):
  pass
```

Then I checked the peak memory usage ("average resident set size") like this:

```
/usr/bin/time -v python run.py
```

Here are the results:

1. n_proc = 5, vec_size = 10^6, peak memory=80,000 kb
2. n_proc = 10, vec_size = 10^6, peak memory=80,000 kb
3. n_proc = 5, vec_size = 10^7, peak memory=360,000 kb
4. n_proc = 10, vec_size = 10^7, peak memory=360,000 kb

My understanding is that the parent process is not creating any data, while the [n_proc] child processes are creating big vectors. But then:

- Going from 5 processes to 10 processes does not change the peak memory usage. This suggests that only the peak memory usage of the parent process is reported. But then 80,000 kb seems too high for the parent process alone
- going from 10^6 elements to 10^7 elements increases the peak memory usage. This suggests that the peak memory of all processes (parent + N child processes) is measured. But then, shouldn't the peak memory usage be multiplied by 10?

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: "shouldn't the peak memory usage be multiplied by 10?" in regards to this: No. You need to remember that the forked processes even with no big array in them will occupy non-trivial amount of memory so that's why you don't see 10-fold increase most likely. You can maybe test how much memory it takes if you don't construct any arrays.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're only measuring the size of the parent process (`man /usr/bin/time` doesn't mention child processes at all so I doubt it does anything fancy to measure them).

Comment: You could have a look at the memory usage in a process viewer to check, e.g. htop (press f5 to get a tree view which shows child and parent processes together).

Comment: The [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) package works well for measuring peak memory of Python processes including child processes in the multiprocessing context. e.g. as a CLI tool `mprof run --include-children <script>`